# Need a help in image upload using php

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I have two server and I have an browse button in server1 (ie `input=file`) from server 1 i need to upload images to server2. How can I do this?
Now I have done upload image to server1 and from there I am trying to move to server2. Here is the code which I have done so far

After uploading to server 1 I have written this code

```
$uploadedfile = $_FILES[$fileElementName]['tmp_name'] ;
$data = array('name' =>  $newname, 'file' => $uploadedfile);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://server.xx/upload.php');
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

and in server2 I have created one file upload.php
in that I have written

```
$content = $_POST['file'];
$imageString = file_get_contents("http://server.xx/temp/".$_POST['name']);
$save = file_put_contents("/dddd/".$_POST['name'],$imageString);
```

I think I have done wrong in upload.php file.. I don’t have any idea to do it.. please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do on server to Server 2:

```
 $from = ''; //Absolute path to server 1 image
 $to = ''; relative path to your server 2 place.
 copy($from, $to);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?PHP   
    $ch = curl_init('http://server.xx/upload.php');
    $ch = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    $ch = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file' => $_FILES[$fileElementName]['tmp_name'] ));
    $ch = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username:password');

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
       die(curl_error($ch));
    }
?>
```